# Want to build simple SQL admin interface to change a few values in a table

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently building a system in SQL Server 2005.

I have a table that holds information about certain insurance schemes such as overheads and other things. These values will change occasionally and currently I administer the database straight through the management Studio.

I would like to build a simple interface that will allow my colleagues to change these values by selecting the company in a dropdown and the current values will populate. They can then edit these values and submit them to the database.

Is this possible in the current Visual Studio supplied with SQL Server 2005 or do I need to get another product.

I am confident that with the help of stack overflow and google I can build this myself, but I need pointed in the right direction as to which environment would be easiest and best to start building it.

Many thanks,

adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata)? Might be [ideal](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx). It's very quick to get up and running with it and might be exactly what you need with little effort.

ASP.NET Dynamic Data brings major usability and RAD development changes to the existing ASP.NET data controls. **RAD development is significantly increased by the use of a rich scaffolding framework. After you add a LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework data model to a project, you can simply register it with Dynamic Data. The result is a fully functional Web site. Full CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) operations are supported.** The site includes filtering by foreign keys and Boolean fields; foreign keys are automatically converted to their friendly names. Smart validation is automatically available, which provides validation based on database constraints for nullable fields, data type, and field length.

Comment: +1 Beat me to the answer!!!!  Dynamic Data has been described on many occasions as the perfect fit for this type of need.

Comment: cheers guys, i'm not sure whether our IT rules will allow me to use the IIS services, but im hoping they will because i want to use the reoprting services tools eventually.